# Override parent init block in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, oop, init

When i create instance of a subclass i don't want parent's class init block to print the message.

Example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var instance2 = Child()

}

open class Parent() {
    init{
        println("This is a parent object")
    }
    
    
}

class Child: Parent(){
    init{
        println("This is a child object")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is a parent object // Don't want this
This is a child object
```

I found this way:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var instance2 = Child()

}

open class Parent() {
    init {
        initMethod()
    }
    
    open fun initMethod(){
        println("This is a parent object")
    }
    
    
}

class Child: Parent(){
    override fun initMethod(){
        println("This is a child object")
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
This is a child object
```

But this doesn't seem appropriate to me. initMethod is open and public and it should be private.

There must be more legitimate way of doing this?

Comment: Do you control `Parent` or is it a 3rd party code? I think your root problem is that you put some code in the constructor which probably shouldn't be there. Constructor is for initializing an object, initializing its internal state and for this reason we can't override its behavior. What is your real use case?

Comment: Good point, I was giving it the benefit of the doubt but it could be an XY problem. The fact that you want to selectively initialize something is a red flag and violates basic OOP principles.

Comment: I will check what i am doing wrong, thanks for warning. @Tenfour4 your answer solved my issue anyways. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should never call an open function or property from your constructor.

Maybe you could do this with a protected constructor:

```
open class Parent protected constructor(runParentInitMethod: Boolean) {

    constructor(): this(true)

    init {
        if (runParentInitMethod) initMethod()
    }
    
    private fun initMethod(){
        println("This is a parent object")
    }
    
}

class Child: Parent(false) {

    init {
        childInitMethod()
    }

    private fun childInitMethod(){
        println("This is a child object")
    }
    
}
```